# How to horizontally align cell content when some cell of the table contain image?

Tags: tables, graphics

[image]

I want to horizontally align the cell content.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
Image & Name & weight & price\\
\toprule
\hspace*{-.8cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{Image/dabbasPk.png} & Dabbas & 400gm & 100tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Image/dabbasCrownPk.jpg} & Dabbas Crown & 1kg & 270tk\\
\hspace*{-.15cm}\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{Image/neghalCrownPk.jpg} & Neghal Crown & 800gm & 220tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{Image/zahdiPk.jpg} & Zahdi & 500gm & 90tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{Image/zahdiCrownPk.jpeg} & Zahdi Crown & 1kg & 200tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Image/raisin.jpg} & Raisin(Dried grape) & 100gm & 45tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image/raisinBlack.jpg} & Raizin(light Black) & 100gm & 50tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Image/blackSeed.jpg} & Black Seed & 100gm & 40tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image/woodNut.jpg} & Woodnut & 100gm & 100tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{Image/1.jpg} & Black Seed's Oil & 70ml & 160tk\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{Image/1.jpg} & Sesame's Oil & 70ml & 100tk\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean vertically center the images not horizontally, did I get it right? OK, here is a new macro `\newcommand{\pcntr}[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}` which perfectly centers the images vertically. Note also that instead of manually adding `\hspace` you can set a common width for all pictures as `[width=<some common value>]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}

\newcommand{\pcntr}[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
Image                                              & Name                & weight & price \\
\toprule
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Dabbas              & 400gm  & 100tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Dabbas Crown        & 1kg    & 270tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Neghal Crown        & 800gm  & 220tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Zahdi               & 500gm  & 90tk  \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Zahdi Crown         & 1kg    & 200tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Raisin(Dried grape) & 100gm  & 45tk  \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Raizin(light Black) & 100gm  & 50tk  \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Black Seed          & 100gm  & 40tk  \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Woodnut             & 100gm  & 100tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Black Seed's Oil    & 70ml   & 160tk \\
\pcntr{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Sesame's Oil        & 70ml   & 100tk \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

anther solution based on use of the `adjustbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}      % it also load graphicx package
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \adjustboxset{width=20mm,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
\begin{tabular}{lllr<{\,tk}}
    \toprule
Image                              & Name                & weight & \multicolumn{1}{c}{price} \\
    \midrule
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Dabbas              & 400gm  & 100 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Dabbas Crown        & 1kg    & 270 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Neghal Crown        & 800gm  & 220 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Zahdi               & 500gm  & 90  \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Zahdi Crown         & 1kg    & 200 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Raisin(Dried grape) & 100gm  & 45  \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Raizin(light Black) & 100gm  & 50  \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Black Seed          & 100gm  & 40  \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Woodnut             & 100gm  & 100 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Black Seed's Oil    & 70ml   & 160 \\
\adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} & Sesame's Oil        & 70ml   & 100 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```